# Dropdown change event not firing in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

I'm having some problems with some jQuery function not working in IE11 (works ok in Chrome).

For giving some context - I have a dropdown with years which certain logic should only be applied when you had previously selected a year prior 2000 and switch to a year 2000 or later.
Is there a way to make this work in both browsers (and others)?

```
var sel = $("#myDropdown");
sel.data("prev",sel.val());

sel.change(function(data){
     var jqThis = $(this);
     var year = jqThis.val();


     if ((jqThis.data("prev") < 2000 && year > 1999)) {
        $(".someElements").prop("style", "display:block");
        $(".otherElements").prop("style", "display:none");
        $('select#otherDropdown').val('').trigger('liszt:updated');
        calculate();
     }
    
     jqThis.data("prev",year);
}
```

**UPDATE:** I don't see any errors in the console. After some testing and adding some alerts I can see that everything is worked as expected except the update of the other dropdown which uses the chosen jquery library:

```
    $('select#otherDropdown').val('').trigger('liszt:updated');
```

Comment: I suggest the sites http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ https://caniuse.com/ and the keyword you are looking for is "polyfill"

Comment: What is the ```not working```? what is the expected behavior?

Comment: We need more debugging information - where is the error generated? What specifically doesn't work? What is the logic in `calculate()`? Does it contain any ES6 methods which IE won't support?

Comment: @ikhvjs  Apparently it all works except the update of the other dropdown. This line doesn't seem to work in IE11 $('select#otherDropdown').val('').trigger('liszt:updated');

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself as I've found what was the problem and the solution for it.

The following instructions are not correct as style is an attribute of the element and not a property. Funny thing is that they were still working on Chrome.

```
    $(".someElements").prop("style", "display:block");
    $(".otherElements").prop("style", "display:none");
```

Replacing this by the below using the .attr made this work in different browsers.

```
   $(".someElements").attr("style", "display:block");
    $(".otherElements").attr("style", "display:none");
```